# Why are functor categories nice?

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

I was looking at the Yoneda embedding and one motivation is that we are embedding the category into a functor category and "functor categories are nice". What does this mean? What nice properties do functor categories have?

Comment: Edit: Since the only answer that has appeared below is for the functor category into  **SET**, I wonder is the nice properties people refer to are only for this category? Or are functor categories nice in general?

Comment: Generally speaking, functor categories inherit nice properties from their codomain.  So $\mathrm{Fun}(C,\mathrm{Set})$ is nice because $\rm Set$ is.  For instance, the same argument in Ben's answer shows that if $D$ is complete and cocomplete, so is $\mathrm{Fun}(C,D)$.

Comment: There's also a sense in which functor categories in general "can't be any nicer than their codomain", since every category $D$ is equivalent to a functor category, namely $\mathrm{Fun}(1,D)$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a (locally small) category. One good property of the functor category $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathrm{Set})$ is that it is complete and cocomplete. In other words arbitrary limits and colimits exists. Since they exist in $\mathrm{Set}$, one can show that in general for any diagram $F$ in $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathrm{Set})$ and $X \in \mathcal{C}$ one has

$$(\lim_i F_i)(X)=\lim_i (F_i(X)) \quad \text{and} \quad (\underset{i}{\mathrm{colim}}F_i)(X)=\underset{i}{\mathrm{colim}}(F_i(X)). $$